# Java 11 - Byte.MIN_VALUE & Byte.MAX_VALUE are showing errors in IntelliJ IDEA CE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get the minimum and maximum values of the byte data type printed but the `Byte.MIN_VALUE` & the `Byte.MAX_VALUE` are highlighted in red in the IDE. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA community edition. Would someone be able to help, please? Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Byte {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        byte myMaxByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;

        System.out.println("Byte Minimum Value = " + myMinByteValue);
        System.out.println("Byte Maximum Value = " + myMaxByteValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: replace with `java.lang.Byte. MIN_VALUE` and check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared your own `Byte` class.  (Bad idea ...)

Within your `Byte` class, references to `Byte` are referring to >>this<< class, not to `java.lang.Byte`.  But your `Byte` class does not declare `MIN_VALUE` or `MAX_VALUE`.  Hence the compilation error ... indicated by the red highlighting.

Solutions:

1. Change the name of your class.  It is a bad idea to use a name for your class that is the same as the name of a standard class.  If leads to various confusing compilation errors ....
2. Use the qualified name for the standard class; i.e. change

   ```
    byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
   ```

   to

   ```
    byte myMinByteValue = java.lang.Byte.MIN_VALUE;
   ```

Answer (score 5):

You are giving Class Name as **Byte** so its refer the same class name. Change the class name to some other name .

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        byte myMaxByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;

        System.out.println("Byte Minimum Value = " + myMinByteValue);
        System.out.println("Byte Maximum Value = " + myMaxByteValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"**Byte**" is a reserved word or "keyword" of Java. You can’t use any reserved word as a *class*, *variable*, or *function name*. Change your class name.

```java
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        byte myMaxByteValue = Byte.MAX_VALUE;

        System.out.println("Byte Minimum Value = " + myMinByteValue);
        System.out.println("Byte Maximum Value = " + myMaxByteValue);
    }
}
```